# How to track unidentified users in web and Mobile analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We are using the web and mobile analytics for tracking data from the website into marketing cloud via IGO and PI data extension. We are able to track identified users that means when they logged into our website we can track them using below code

```
function sendUserInfo() {
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "*******"]);
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", { "email": uname }]);
```

}

But the challenging we are facing here is how to track the unregistered users who visited our site.

what we have tried till now:

We created a custom field in IGO_profiles called Cookie ID and we included this field in the setUserinfo function, but it is not tracking any info of cookieID(support confirmed that for now analytics DE's doesn't support custom fields)

**can anyone shed some light on this how to capture unregistered or unidentified users**

Note: I have gone through the documentation but it's of no use

Comment: What do you mean with regards to unidentified users? All users are tracked, and the user_id field in e.g. IGO_VIEWS corresponds to the cookie ID set by the collect code. Only users where you execute setUserInfo have email filed populated in IGO_PROFILES

Comment: Cookie ID is not collecting any unidentified users, even if it creates any unique ID in DE it will be helpful but nothing is being tracking. If you achieve this scenario can you help us understand how you did it

Answer (score 3):

Unidentified (anonymous) visitors are automatically assigned a cookie with an ID by IGO Collect scripts, on the domain: `igodigital.com` - this is the domain where the tracking scripts are served from.

You should look for the cookie named: `igodigitaltc2`, which contains the uuid assigned to your browser:
[image: IGO cookie]

When you look in e.g. **IGO_VIEWS** of **PI_CONTENTVIEWS** Data Extensions, you will see same value show in the *user_id* column:

[image: IGO_VIEWS Data Extension]

Hence linking the behaviour to a specific user across page views and sessions. Once you execute `_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", { "email": uname }]);` call, this user_id gets linked to your *own* identifier, passed in the place of `uname` in your example above. Only these users who are identified will be found in **IGO_PROFILES** Data Extension, allowing you link them to your own contact data (`user_id` is the cookie ID above, and `email` is your identifier sent to `setUserInfo` call):

[image]